# Selecting highest value that may or may not be necessarily the Max value from column

Tags: sql

Let’s say I have one table column named ‘CarMaker’ where I may have Honda, Toyota, Ford and so on. On a second column I have ‘CarYear’, like 1999, 1958, 2006 and so on. How can I write a query to get a Toyota where the year is the highest of all Toyotas but it is not necessarily the MAX value of all cars in the column.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars
WHERE ( CarModel, CarYear ) = (
   SELECT CarModel, max( CarYear )
   FROM cars   
   WHERE CarModel = 'Toyota'
   GROUP BY CarModel
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general way to solve this problem:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CarMaker, MAX(year) AS max_year
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY CarMaker
) t2
    ON t1.CarMaker = t2.CarMaker AND t1.year = t2.max_year;
```

This would return the latest model for all car makers.  If you want to restrict to a particular car maker, then you may add a `WHERE` clause to the end of the above query:

```
WHERE t1.CarMaker = 'Toyota'
```

Note than this would return all Toyota models which happen to appear in the most recent year, so if more than one model fits this category, then all would be returned.  If you don't want this behavior, then you should give us logic regarding which of the most recent models should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT CarMaker, MAX(CarYear) as mxYear
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY CarMaker
) WHERE CarMaker = 'Toyota'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function:

```
select *
from (
  select carmaker, 
         caryear, 
         max(caryear) over (partition by carmaker) as max_year
  from the_table
) t
where caryear = max_year
  and carmaker = 'Toyota';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `subquery` with *correlation* approach :

```
select c.*
from cars c
where CarYear = (select max(c1.CarYear) 
                 from cars c1
                 where c1.CarModel = c.CarModel
                );
```

However, this would may give you duplicate records if so, then you can `PK` instead :

```
select c.*
from cars c
where pk = (select pk -- top (1) if your has no support of limit clause
            from cars c1
            where c1.CarModel = c.CarModel
            order by c1.CarYear desc
            limit 1 -- DBMS specific some other uses TOP clause instead
            );
```